# Visual Studio 2013 doesn't appear to install

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

I have downloaded and installed Visual Studio 2010 (kind of successfully, but that's another story), and then attempted to install Visual Studio 2013 (update 2). The install tells me that it's finished successfully, but the application is nowhere to be found, despite all of the associated files and blend showing up. I don't think that this is a compatibility issue, but I have uninstalled and reinstalled VS2010 about 3 times, so that may have done something. 
 
Both versions of VS were obtained legitimately through the Microsoft Dreamspark student program. 
I would prefer to avoid reinstalling windows, if at all possible. 
Images as proof: 
[VS2010 installed correctly](http://puu.sh/94h4D.png) 
[Suspicious lack of the VS2013 program folder](http://puu.sh/94h8k.png)

Comment: Does Visual Studio 2013 show up in the Control Panel's list of installed programs?  If so, try repairing the installation there.  Otherwise, just try installing VS2013 again over the old installation.

Comment: Looks like it installed properly to me—the second picture shows the VS 2013 installation folder. Why do you think "the application is nowhere to be found"?

Comment: VS2013 appears in the list of applications, but when I search through my computer, only blend shows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the image you posted, you're in the folder that Visual Studio 2013 installed in. You'll find it here:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe

Comment: Thanks! I guess I was looking in the wrong place. Don't know why Windows wouldn't show it to me though..